# Scheme - car/cdr on empty list

Tags: scheme

I wrote a big program that use car and cdr, and do:

```
(map car (append (map caddr lists) (map cadr lists))
```

When `lists` is list of lists in the next format `((a (b) (c)) (d (e) (f))...(x (y) (z)))`
When I did it I got one list `(b c e f... y z)`
(Note: b,c,...y,z is a list of numbers; a,d...x is a symbol)

But now, I found that b,c,...,y,z can be also empty list, and It gives the next error:

```
car: expects argument of type <pair>; given ()
```

What can I do?

Comment: So what do you want it to do if (b c ...) is empty? Return the empty list?

Comment: @shaun: Nothing. I dont need them in (b c....). I try to delete the empty list, but it didn't succssed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried filtering away empty lists before your `map`? Something like this:

```
(map car (filter pair? (append (map caddr lists) (map cadr lists))))
```

The fundamental issue is that `()` is not a pair while `car` only acts on pairs. The simplest solution is just to get rid of everything that isn't a pair before mapping `car` onto the list; this is what `(filter pair? ...)` does.

Comment: I believe it should be `(map car (filter pair? (append (map caddr lists) (map cadr lists))))`

Comment: @mangoDrunk: You're right; I just wasn't paying enough attention.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my shot. It's a straight solution, without using `map`, `filter`; in that way, I avoid going over and over the elements of the list constructing intermediate lists - except that I used a `reverse` operation for preserving the original order of the elements, if that's not an issue, remove `reverse`. For each element in the original list, if either the (b)... *or* (c)... part is empty, it's skipped.

```
(define (process lists)
  (let loop ((l (reverse lists))
             (a '())
             (b '()))
    (cond ((null? l)
           (append b a))
          ((or (not (pair? (cadar l))) (not (pair? (caddar l))))
           (loop (cdr l) a b))
          (else
           (loop (cdr l) (cons (caadar l) a) (cons (car (caddar l)) b))))))
```